# SQLLITE insert statement fails in android app

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

In my Android APP, I am trying to fetch the details from one table and inserting those records into another table with a join to another table.

The SQLLITE insert statement continuously fails for many times. I have tried a lot to figure out the issue in the INSERT statement, but I am not hitting success.

I have attached the logs , SQL table declarations and the INSERT statement where I am facing the issue. Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

```
        sql = "INSERT INTO  " + DATABASE_TABLE_TRAN  + "   (" +
                KEY_ID    + "," +
                KEY_NAME  + "," +
                KEY_COIN  + "," +
                KEY_DATE  + "," +
                KEY_TYPE  + "," +
                KEY_QTY   + "," +
                KEY_PRICE + "," +
                KEY_PRICE_UNIT  +
                ") " +
                " VALUES (" +
                " SELECT " +
                "TRN." +KEY_ID         + "," +
                "ALT." +KEY_NAME + "," +
                "TRN." +KEY_COIN  + "," +
                "TRN." +KEY_DATE + "," +
                "TRN." +KEY_TYPE + "," +
                "TRN." +KEY_QTY + "," +
                "TRN." +KEY_PRICE + "," +
                "TRN." +KEY_PRICE_UNIT   +
                " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_TRAN_TEMP + " TRN, " +
                           DATABASE_TABLE_ALTCOIN   + " ALT  " +
                " WHERE "  + "TRN."+KEY_COIN  + " = " + "ALT."+KEY_COIN  +
                " )";

        Log.i("Insert Query",sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
```

**Logcat**

```
12-21 09:35:30.776 5901-5901/? I/Insert Query: INSERT INTO  TB_TRAN   (ID,NAME,COIN,DATE,TYPE,QTY,PRICE,PRICE_UNIT)  VALUES ( SELECT TRN.ID,ALT.NAME,TRN.COIN,TRN.DATE,TRN.TYPE,TRN.QTY,TRN.PRICE,TRN.PRICE_UNIT FROM TB_TRAN_TEMP TRN, TB_ALTCOIN ALT   WHERE TRN.COIN = ALT.COIN )
12-21 09:35:30.776 5901-5901/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "SELECT": syntax error
12-21 09:35:30.792 5901-5901/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-21 09:35:30.794 5901-5901/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.xx.xx.xx, PID: 5901
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xx.xx.xx/com.xx.xx.xx.AndroidLauncher}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO  TB_TRAN   (ID,NAME,COIN,DATE,TYPE,QTY,PRICE,PRICE_UNIT)  VALUES ( SELECT TRN.ID,ALT.NAME,TRN.COIN,TRN.DATE,TRN.TYPE,TRN.QTY,TRN.PRICE,TRN.PRICE_UNIT FROM TB_TRAN_TEMP TRN, TB_ALTCOIN ALT   WHERE TRN.COIN = ALT.COIN )
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO  TB_TRAN   (ID,NAME,COIN,DATE,TYPE,QTY,PRICE,PRICE_UNIT)  VALUES ( SELECT TRN.ID,ALT.NAME,TRN.COIN,TRN.DATE,TRN.TYPE,TRN.QTY,TRN.PRICE,TRN.PRICE_UNIT FROM TB_TRAN_TEMP TRN, TB_ALTCOIN ALT   WHERE TRN.COIN = ALT.COIN )
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1676)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
                                                     at a.a$a.onUpgrade(SourceFile:453)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                     at a.a.a(SourceFile:495)
                                                     at com.xx.xx.xx.AndroidLauncher.s(SourceFile:1252)
                                                     at com.xx.xx.xx.AndroidLauncher.g(SourceFile:1727)
                                                     at com.xx.xx.xx.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(SourceFile:240)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
```

**Table declarations**

```
        String DATABASE_TABLE_TRAN_TEMP   = "TB_TRAN_TEMP";

        sql="CREATE TABLE "      +
                DATABASE_TABLE_TRAN_TEMP      +
                "("                 +
                KEY_TRAN_ID         + " INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,  "  +
                KEY_ID              + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_COIN            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_DATE            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_TYPE            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_QTY             + " DECIMAL(19, 2)  NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PRICE           + " DECIMAL(19, 2)  NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PRICE_UNIT      + " TEXT            NOT NULL   "  +
                ");";
        //Log.i("Create Query",sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);


        String DATABASE_TABLE_TRAN        = "TB_TRAN";

        sql="CREATE TABLE "      +
                DATABASE_TABLE_TRAN      +
                "("                 +
                KEY_TRAN_ID         + " INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,  "  +
                KEY_ID              + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_NAME            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  + /* added in version 2 */
                KEY_COIN            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_DATE            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_TYPE            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_QTY             + " DECIMAL(19, 2)  NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PRICE           + " DECIMAL(19, 2)  NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PRICE_UNIT      + " TEXT            NOT NULL   "  +
                ");";

        //Log.i("Create Query",sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);

        sql="CREATE TABLE "      +
                DATABASE_TABLE_ALTCOIN      +
                "("                 +
                KEY_ID              + " TEXT            PRIMARY KEY,  "  +
                KEY_NAME            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_COIN            + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_RANK            + " INTEGER         NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PRICE           + " DECIMAL(19, 2)  NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PRICE_UNIT      + " TEXT            NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PRICE_BTC       + " VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PERC_CHANGE_1H  + " DECIMAL(5, 2)   NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PERC_CHANGE_24H + " DECIMAL(5, 2)   NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_PERC_CHANGE_7D  + " DECIMAL(5, 2)   NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_VOL_24HR        + " VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_MKT_CAP         + " VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,  "  +
                KEY_FAV_TEMP            + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0  "  +
                ");";
        //Log.i("Create Query",sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shoult not be `VALUES` keyword while using `insert into ... select ...` statement.

Remove

```
" VALUES (" +
```

and

```
" )";
```

from your code.

Should be:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO  " + DATABASE_TABLE_TRAN  + "   (" +
    KEY_ID    + "," +
    KEY_NAME  + "," +
    KEY_COIN  + "," +
    KEY_DATE  + "," +
    KEY_TYPE  + "," +
    KEY_QTY   + "," +
    KEY_PRICE + "," +
    KEY_PRICE_UNIT  +
    ") " +
    " SELECT " +
    "TRN." +KEY_ID         + "," +
    "ALT." +KEY_NAME + "," +
    "TRN." +KEY_COIN  + "," +
    "TRN." +KEY_DATE + "," +
    "TRN." +KEY_TYPE + "," +
    "TRN." +KEY_QTY + "," +
    "TRN." +KEY_PRICE + "," +
    "TRN." +KEY_PRICE_UNIT   +
    " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_TRAN_TEMP + " TRN, " +
               DATABASE_TABLE_ALTCOIN   + " ALT  " +
    " WHERE "  + "TRN."+KEY_COIN  + " = " + "ALT." + KEY_COIN;
```